# Why do I need to enter my password for apt update?

Tags: apt, software-updates

I can understand why you need to enter your password for an `sudo apt install daSoftware` or even `sudo apt upgrade`: you are modifying the code that will run on your machine.

But why on `apt update`? You are just updating the list of available software. **Why would it be a problem not to ask for the extra privilege granted by the super user mode to perform an update?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of software is written in protected areas (`/var/lib/apt/`*#1*) you don't have write access to. The elevated permissions are required to write into that directory where all users can read, but not write.

*#1: @jordanm correctly pointed this directory out; thanks Jordan*

Answer (score -1):

Because everything you do with `sudo` requires a password by default, and there's no exception for that in your sudoers file (though you could add one via NOPASSWD if you want).